# Conda stopped installing pandas v0.17.0

Tags: python, pandas, osx-elcapitan, conda

The instruction at http://pandas.pydata.org to install pandas v0.17.0 using `conda install pandas -c pandas` seems to have stopped working. I was quite happily using it to re-install 0.17.0rc1 after each `conda update --all`, but for the last few days it has insisted on re-installing v0.16.2.
Two things have changed - pandas has now gone to 0.17.0rc2, and I have updated my OS X to 10.11 El Capitan. I think these are the only changes.
So, is conda behaving differently under El Capitan than under Yosemite or (and?) has the introduction of rc2 had an unexpected effect on the behaviour of conda? Anyone else seeing the same?

Comment: I have El Capitan and have not been able to update to 0.17 (although I coudn't before my update, so I don't think it is related).  Both versions are marked as Pre-release: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/releases

Comment: Problem no longer relevant. Conda now handles pandas package as expected.

Answer (score 1):

See also this issue:https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11254. A workaround proposed there is to do:

```
conda install -c pandas pandas=v0.17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the anaconda.org channel and see which packages are available for your OS and Python version:

https://anaconda.org/pandas/pandas/files?version=v0.17.0rc2

Any chance you're using Python 3.3?

Also maybe check if using the full channel like this works:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/pandas pandas
```